# Add foreground within borders

Tags: android, xml

I have a recylcerview with borders, and i want to add an animation to the bordered area only, how do i add it? I want to add `android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"` such that when row is clicked, only the bordered area displays the animation, not the whole row

Recycler View

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">



    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Row item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/pokedex_row"
    android:padding="10sp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:background="@drawable/card_background"
    android:elevation="12dp"
    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/pokedex_row_text_view"
        android:layout_margin="10sp"

        />

</LinearLayout>
```

background of row

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:left="8dp"
        android:right="3dp"
        android:top="8dp"
        android:bottom="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#CBAAAAAA"
                android:width="1dp"/>
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:left="5dp"
        android:right="5dp"
        android:top="5dp"
        android:bottom="5dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the **ripple** tag instead of layer-list to acheive the required behaviour.

**Note:** This will work only for API 21+(Lollipop).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
tools:targetApi="lollipop" android:color="?colorControlNormal">
<item
    android:left="8dp"
    android:right="3dp"
    android:top="8dp"
    android:bottom="2dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#CBAAAAAA"
            android:width="1dp"/>
        <corners android:radius="5dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:left="5dp"
    android:right="5dp"
    android:top="5dp"
    android:bottom="5dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
        <corners android:radius="5dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```